# Where can I find the 1960s New Math syllabus?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, education

I've been looking everywhere for even a short summary of the content of the 1960s New Mathematics Math education reform in the US but I cannot ;-;

Does anyone know?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math#Modern_exercises. Maybe you can get your hands on: Kline, Morris (1973). Why Johnny Can't Add: The Failure of the New Math. New York: St. Martin's Press. ISBN 0-394-71981-6

Comment: Not really a mathematics question...

Comment: @lhf Seems to fit its tags (reference-request, math-history, and education) quite well to me.

Comment: *sigh* I used to own a complete set of the SMSG texts and teachers’ guides, but I finally got rid of them a number of years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the primary source would be the documents created by the [School Mathematics Study Group](http://www.maa.org/the-school-mathematics-study-group-records).

> [...] the School Mathematics Study Group (SMSG) created and implemented a primary and secondary school curriculum between 1958 and 1977 that was widely known as the "new math."

Some films made by the group are found [here](http://www.cah.utexas.edu/collections/math_smsg_gallery.php).

(For context surrounding the "New Math" reform, see "[A Brief History of American K-12 Mathematics Education in the 20th Century](http://www.csun.edu/~vcmth00m/AHistory.html)" by David Klein.)

Answer (score 2):

The book, *The New Mathematics Made Simple* by Kempf and Murphy, is available online in PDF format.  It should give you a pretty good grasp of what was being taught back then.